# Which models of the Boeing 737 are still in production?

Tags: boeing-737

The BBC is reporting that [the production of 737 aircraft has been reduced](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business-47834556) from 52 to 42 per month due to a loss of 737-Max orders.  It isn't clear in the report whether the Max is the only 737 being made now.

Does Boeing currently produce any other models of the 737 or is the Max the only one?

Comment: More than half the models that ever existed are still in production.

Comment: By the way, neither Boeing nor the BBC article said that the production cut is because of a drop in orders. The most recent order numbers on Boeing's website are actually higher than they were in February. [Boeing's statement](https://boeing.mediaroom.com/2019-04-05-Statement-from-Boeing-CEO-Dennis-Muilenburg-We-Own-Safety-737-MAX-Software-Production-and-Process-Update) said that the production cut was temporary and was to allow them "to prioritize additional resources to focus on software certification and returning the MAX to flight."

Comment: @reirab  Do you think that Boeing's statement is accurate?  They have about 5,000 unfulfilled orders and you can't really move aircraft fabricators to software certification?  Although, the only definite cancellations to date are the 49 Garuda aircraft.  There's an interesting article about the difficulties of cancelling here: https://www.businessinsider.com/boeing-737-max-8-orders-unlikely-canceled-experts-2019-3?r=US&IR=T   But I guess the customers could change to other 737 models???

Comment: @DaveGremlin It's unlikely that they would change to NGs. Operators don't spook as easily as the news media. They understand that they're talking about a potentially 20+ year investment. It's similarly unlikely that many will cancel unless something changes dramatically for the worst in the next few months. I would guess it's engineering resources that Boeing needed to move around for a while. With something as complicated as airliner production, those are still required. At any rate, significant order cancellation is completely unsubstantiated (and unlikely) speculation at this point.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The variants [in production](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_Commercial_Airplanes#Aircraft_in_production_or_development) are:

- **[700](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_737_Next_Generation)**
- **[800](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_737_Next_Generation)**
- **[900ER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_737_Next_Generation)**
- BBJ
- C-40
- 737 AEW&C
- P-8
- **[MAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_737_MAX)**

In bold are the passenger variants. The BBJ is a business jet variant. The first three are 737 Next Generation. As of February 28, 2019, there is a total of 38 [unfilled orders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_737_Next_Generation#Orders_and_deliveries) for that family (discounting the military P-8). Whereas there are 4,636 unfilled MAX orders as of the same date.

Comment: +1 Duh, it didn't occur to me that Wikipedia would have current production levels

Comment: The MAX is at least 2, the Max 8 and 9.

Comment: @Harper The MAX 10 is also currently being assembled, though none have been delivered yet. And, if you consider it separate from the MAX 8, the MAX 200 is also in production.

Comment: The MAX 7 is also in production, though it doesn't have a lot of orders.

Answer (score 5):

By contrast, here are the models that are no longer in production.

- 737-100 Original (93' long, 85-118 seats) not replaced
- 737-200 Original (100' long, 102-130 seats) replaced by -500 Classic
- 737-300 Classic (110' long, 126-149 seats) replaced by -700 NG
- 737-400 Classic (120' long, 147-168 seats) see longer -800 NG
- 737-500 Classic (short 102' long, 110-132 seats) replaced by -600 NG
- 737-600 Next Gen (short 103' long, 108-130 seats) not replaced

Comment: The 737-900 (non-ER) isn't in production either.